# How to navigate html using bs4?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

just started learning python this afternoon. Trying to scrape the rss feed of kubuntu.org (simple html) as practice but I can't figure out how to navigate the html and only print the feedTitle:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

site = urllib.request.urlopen('https://kubuntu.org/feed').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(site, 'lxml')

for title in soup.find_all('item'):
    print(title.text)
```

EDIT:

adding `title` to the `find_all` line kinda gives me what I want but there's still a ton of data that also uses the title tag.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

site = urllib.request.urlopen('https://kubuntu.org/feed').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(site, 'lxml')

for title in soup.find_all(['item', 'title']):
    print(title.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just access `title` tag as `item`'s child node:

```
...
for item in soup.find_all('item'):
    print(item.title.text)
```

The output:

```
Kubuntu Artful Aardvark (17.10) Alpha 1
Latest round of backports PPA updates include Plasma 5.10.2 for Zesty 17.04
Plasma 5.10.1 now in Zesty backports
17.10 Wallpaper Contest deadline for submissions soon
Plasma bugfix releases, Frameworks, & selected app updates now available in backports PPA for Zesty and Xenial
17.10 Wallpaper Contest! Call for artists
KDE PIM update now available for Zesty Zapus 17.04
KDE PIM update for Zesty available for testers
Kubuntu 17.04 Released!
Kubuntu 17.04 Release Candidate – call for testers
```